# How to setup a domain server for manage windows pc's & ubuntu pc's?

Tags: server, samba, ldap, domain-server

i like to manage windows pc's and ubuntu pc's.Can some one explain me on setting up a ubuntu domain server step by step configuration

Comment: You'll probably want to provide some more information about what, exactly you want (since a step-by-step would be different for a setup with "shared drives" or remote personal storage than without), as well as Windows versions. And for that matter, it might help to know *why* you're looking at making a domain (which is, in most home network cases, the "nuclear bomb" method of dealing with a mixed network), in case there's an alternative method. (Please edit your question to provide the extra information.)

Comment: There is an installation/configuration guide on http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html